# Angular.js routing when user successfully logs in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication

I am following this post https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

I have successfully made a `POST` request to the server and I get the user object returned.The below service is what makes the request.

I do not understand where I can then route to the dashboard.

```
/**
 * Authentication service via medium post Service
 *
 */
.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Session, ApiEndpoint) {
  var authService = {};

  authService.login = function (credentials) {
    console.log(credentials)
    return $http
      .post('/api/login', credentials)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.data);
        Session.create(res.data._id, res.data.email);
        return res.data;
      });
  };

  authService.signup = function (credentials) {
    console.log(credentials.username)
    return $http
      .post('/api/signup', credentials)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.data);
        Session.create(res.data._id, res.data.email);
        return res.data;
      });
  };

  authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return !!Session.userId;
  };

  authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
    if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
      authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
    }
    return (authService.isAuthenticated() && authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
  };

  return authService;
})
```

I have disabled viewing the dashboard

```
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashController'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    auth: function resolveAuthentication(AuthResolver) { 
      return AuthResolver.resolve();
    }
  }
})
```

By using an `AuthResolver` service I found on the Medium post

```
/**
 * AuthResolver service via medium post Service
 *
 */
.factory('AuthResolver', function ($q, $rootScope, $state) {
  return {
    resolve: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var unwatch = $rootScope.$watch('currentUser', function (currentUser) {
        if (angular.isDefined(currentUser)) {
          if (currentUser) {
            deferred.resolve(currentUser);
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
            $state.go('user-login');
          }
          unwatch();
        }
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})
```

So I get the majority of it but I cant decode where the actual routing to the dashboard happens?

I am migrating from backbone.js/marionette.js and picked up angular.js yesterday lol so I am new, I am building on ionic and want to leverage that stack so I want to see how fast I can pick up angular.js

Comment: You can simply navigate to '/dash' and the resolve property of that state tells ui-router to ensure the navigation does not occur until the user has logged in.